# how to add my article Title as URL to access it asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, webforms

in WordPress (or etc ) we can add post name for access it by that.

```
www.mywesite.com/post/postname/
```

I don't use parameter to access a

```
www.mywesite.com/post?id=146
```

**how do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the process is known as URL rewriting - you use an HTTP module to capture the URLs of the requests as they arrive and redirect them to the actual ASPX pages that will be processing them.
Scott Gu talks about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net)
Microsoft also have a more detailed article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)